# searchUsers: unable to set option properly

Tags: javascript, database, sdk, kuzzle

I need to get all users from my kuzzle so I tried that:

```
// Getting Users
    const users = await kuzzle.security.searchUsers({ 
      options: {
        size: 25
      }
    });
    
    console.log(users)
```

but the output is `The argument "options" is not allowed at this level of a search query.`
Why it says me that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i just figure out that it is just 2 separate parameter

So here is my working code :

```
const users = await kuzzle.security.searchUsers({}, {
  size: 10000
});
```